# Search directory and subdirectories for file matching a string and listing paths using ls and grep instead of find

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, ls

I know there is a nice Linux program called `find`, which used as

```
find /home/user -name ".txt"
```

will print all the files with `.txt` extension with their relative path

How can I achieve the same using `ls`, `grep` and possibly `awk`?

I tried listing all files in directory and its subdirectories recursively using

```
ls -LR1
```

but have no idea how to parse it using `grep`.

Any advice would be greatly appraciated.

Comment: Advice - do not do this. Just use the correct tools for each job. Google "parse ls output".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4) and [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) :

```
shopt -s globstar # required if not enabled with bash4
printf '%s\n' **/*.txt
```

But don't trust anyone finding a solution with `ls` + `awk`, not the good way to achieve this with robustness